# how to extract fields from a struct within an enum (irrefutable if-let pattern)

Tags: enums, rust

I am trying to make an `S3` client library but since there are many [actions (API_Operations)](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/API_Operations.html) I decided to use an `enum` to define all the posible actions in the hope that could be more easy to maintain *(any advice/comments/feedback?)*, for example this is the `enum Actions::ListObjectsV2` snippet for listing the contents of a bucket:

```
pub enum Actions {
    // missing options, POC for now 
    ListObjectsV2 {
        continuation_token: Option<String>,
        delimiter: Option<String>,
        fetch_owner: Option<bool>,
        prefix: Option<String>,
        start_after: Option<String>,
    },
}
```

Is used  with something like this:

```
let s3 = S3::new(&bucket, &credentials, &region);
let action = Actions::ListObjectsV2 {
    continuation_token: None,
    delimiter: None,
    fetch_owner: None,
    prefix: Some(String::from("foo")),
    start_after: None,
};

if let Ok(objects) = s3.list_objects(action).await {
    println!("objects: {:#?}", objects);
}
```

The `s3.list_objects(action)` method looks like this:

```
pub async fn list_objects(
    &self,
    action: Actions,
) -> Result<ListBucketResult, Box<dyn error::Error>> {
    let mut url = Url::parse(&format!("https://{}/{}", self.host, self.bucket))?;
    url.query_pairs_mut().append_pair("list-type", "2");

    if let Actions::ListObjectsV2 {
        continuation_token,
        delimiter,
        fetch_owner,
        prefix,
        start_after,
    } = action.clone()
    {
        if let Some(token) = continuation_token {
            url.query_pairs_mut()
                .append_pair("continuation-token", &token);
        }
        if let Some(delimiter) = delimiter {
            url.query_pairs_mut().append_pair("delimiter", &delimiter);
        }
        if fetch_owner.is_some() {
            url.query_pairs_mut().append_pair("fetch-owner", "true");
        }
        if let Some(prefix) = prefix {
            url.query_pairs_mut().append_pair("prefix", &prefix);
        }
        if let Some(sa) = start_after {
            url.query_pairs_mut().append_pair("start-after", &sa);
        }
    }
...
```

It works but I get this warning: **irrefutable if-let pattern**

```
warning: irrefutable if-let pattern
  --> src/s3/mod.rs:49:9
   |
49 | /         if let Actions::ListObjectsV2 {
50 | |             continuation_token,
51 | |             delimiter,
52 | |             fetch_owner,
...  |
72 | |             }
73 | |         }
   | |_________^
   |
   = note: `#[warn(irrefutable_let_patterns)]` on by default
```

I could remove the warning by adding to that block:

```
 #[allow(irrefutable_let_patterns)]
```

But instead, I would like to know if there are better ways to fix this, I tried some options from this post (https://users.rust-lang.org/t/how-do-i-get-rid-of-this-pattern-of-extracting-a-value-from-an-enum/12555/7), but I can't figure out how to implement this pattern:
`impl From<> for Option<>`

Any ideas?

Comment: You get this warning because your enum has single variant, if you'll populate your enum later it will be fine.

Comment: From my perspective, I wouldn't use enum especially for an S3, it has too many actions with too many properties. There is a design from futures-rs which i really like. It groups all actions in a package. It might work for your problem too if you can find the similarities: https://github.com/rust-lang/futures-rs/blob/master/futures-util/src/stream/stream/mod.rs

Comment: @ÖmerErden, thanks for the info/links, I will check it out, If I am right is using modules instead per each "action/option" in where adds the logic per module right?

Comment: Yes preparation details will be kept in individuals instead of a single large function.